# Chainlink Node step 5. Build and Install: getting error code 137 for yarn

Tags: yarnpkg, smartcontracts, chainlink

I am trying to run a [chainlink node from source](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink#install) and am following the install instructions.

I'm currently running `make install`

It looks like the error code says there is not enough memory on my machine, but my linux container on my chrome duet has 50GB. I don't know the problem.
I ran the command:

These are the errors

```
error Command failed with exit code 137.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 137.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
 | `yarn setup` failed with exit code 137
Stopping 2 active children
Aborted execution due to previous error
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

Per the [documentation](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink#install):

> If you got any errors regarding locked yarn package, try running yarn install before this step

So run `yarn install`

Comment: Yes I followed the documentation. I tried to install yarn. also tried install yarn --network-timeout 150000 per documentation. But still got this error.error Command failed with exit code 137. When I googled this error it said it was a memory capacity error. But I have 50GB. requirements for chainlink node 1GB.

Comment: what version of yarn? what is your OS? what version of your OS?

Comment: yarn 1.22.17, chrome OS with a linux container (chrome duet), debian arm64. I watched one of your videos and when I run postgres --version, I get the error -bash: postgres: command not found. So I am not sure I installed postgres correctly. That could be the problem. but when I run psql -- version, I get psql (PostgreSQL) 14.1 (Debian 14.1-1.pgdg100+1). So, I am not sure what to do...

Comment: What happens when you run just `yarn setup`?

Comment: $ node -e "if(process.env.npm_execpath.indexOf('yarn') === -1) throw new Error('Please use yarn to install dependencies\n\n')"
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
warning Resolution field "source-map-support@0.5.16" is incompatible with requested version "source-map-support@^0.5.17"
warning Resolution field "source-map-support@0.5.16" is incompatible with requested version "source-map-support@0.5.12"
warning Resolution field "source-map-support@0.5.16" is incompatible with requested version "source-map-support@0.5.12"

success Already up-to-date.
Done in 5.49s.

Comment: Ok, so you need to make a new question for your yarn installation error

Comment: thanks so much for the continuous help. sometimes it feels like being so lost. much appreciation. I'll research the error message before posting a new question.

Comment: I'm on a chrome duet, so I think I don't have enough RAM.